# Calculating the probability of a vector of standard normal distributed variables.

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X,Y$ be two i.i.d random variables with standard normal distribution which is the probability that the vector $(X,Y)$ to be in the second quadrant with distance to the origin greater than $2$?

What I think I am being asked is to calculate $$\mathbb{P}(X\leq 0,Y\geq 0, X^2+Y^2\leq 4)$$
How do I calculate that probability?

Comment: You have a joint probability of two independent variables so that should make it easier. Also, do you mean $X^2+Y^2\gt 4$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $R$ be the region corresponding to the set of points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}$ such that $x\leq 0$, $y\geq 0$ and $x^2+y^2>4$. Then by independence the joint density of $(X,Y)$ is given by
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)\right).
$$
Then the required probability is given by
$$
p=\int_R f(x,y)\, dx\, dy=\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\int_{2}^\infty\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}r^2\right)r\, dr\,d\theta
$$
by changing to polar coordinates. You should be able to compute the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\rho(x)$ be the usual standard normal density,
$$
\rho(x)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{x^2}2\ ,
$$
so we know the joint density for $(X,Y)$, it is $\rho(x)\rho(y)$ with respect to the standard Lebesgue mass $dx\; dy$, so we have to calculate:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p
&=
\mathbb{P}(X\leq 0,Y\geq 0, X^2+Y^2\color{red}{\geq} 2^2)
\\
&=
\int_{\substack{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\\x<0\\y>0\\x^2+y^2\ge  2^2}}
\rho(x)\; \rho(y)\; dx\; dy
\\
&\qquad\text{ change of variables }(x,y)=(r\cos t,r\sin t)
\\
&=
\int_{r\ge 2}
\int_{t\in(\pi/2,\pi)}
\frac 1{2\pi}
\exp-\frac {r^2}2
\cdot
r\; dr\; dt
\\
&=
\frac \pi 2
\int_{r\ge 2}
\frac 1{2\pi}
\exp-\frac {r^2}2
\cdot \frac 12d(r^2)
\\
&=
\frac 14\left[\ -\exp-\frac{r^2}2\ \right]_{r=2}^\infty 
=\frac 14\exp(-2)\approx 0.0338338208091532\dots\ \ .
\end{aligned}
$$

In such cases i usually also start a computer simulation:

```
sage: import numpy
sage: N = 10**8    # samples
sage: X = numpy.random.normal(size=N)
sage: Y = numpy.random.normal(size=N)
sage: V = (X^2+Y^2)[ (X<0) & (Y>0) ]
sage: nr_goodCases = len( V[ V>= 4 ] )
sage: nr_goodCases
3383058
sage: print "Proportion of good cases ~ %.8f" % (nr_goodCases / N)
Proportion of good cases ~ 0.03383058
```

this time...